# When does a non-member function template have internal linkage?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

C++11 draft, 14.0.4:

> A non-member function template can have internal linkage; any other
>   template name shall have external linkage.

This query is a consequence of separating template declaration and definition. For example, we can write the following in a header file.

```
template <typename T>
bool operator==(T const & l, T const & r);
```

In a single source file, destined to become a single translation unit, we write the definition. We also instantiate it, either implicitly or explicitly, in the same translation unit, for type `foo`.

```
template <typename T>
bool operator==(T const & l, T const & r)
{
  return extract(l) == extract(r); // extract is uninteresting
}
```

In a second translation unit, which can only see the definition from the header, we attempt to use `foo{} == foo{}`, that is, to call the `operator==` which is instantiated elsewhere.

Currently, this "works". The linker patches the two translation units as I hoped it would.

However, if the function template has internal linkage, the link can fail. For example, we can force this by instantiating within an anonymous namespace.

Does the "can" in the spec indicate that the source code controls the linkage (e.g. by `namespace {}`) or that the compiler is permitted to choose whether the instantiation will have internal or external linkage?

I don't believe there is any undefined behaviour here, but I am struggling to convince myself that the linkage chosen is not an implementation detail. Can I rely on the symbol being visible from other translation units, if it has been instantiated in at least one TU in a context that suggests it will be external?

edit: [DR1603](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1603) (thanks Eugene Zavidovsky!) contains a recommendation to erase exactly the sentence quoted above, alongside general rationalisation of linkage rules.

Comment: Maybe, [DR 1603](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1603) will help.

Comment: I think that only linkage of `main` function is implementation-defined. see N3337 3.6.1.3.

Comment: And, of course, ODR violation causes undefined-behavior even if linkages are correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the "can" in the spec indicate that the source code controls the linkage (e.g. by namespace {}) or that the compiler is permitted to choose whether the instantiation will have internal or external linkage?

This is the code that controls the linkage. A function generated from function template has external linkage, unless it is a `static` function template or the template is in unnamed namespace (since C++11).

In other words, one would have to explicitly ask for internal linkage.