# Linkage of non-member template function

Tags: c++, templates, linkage

My own experiments show the instantiation of a non-member template function has internal linkage, however [the answer to this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201090/when-does-a-non-member-function-template-have-internal-linkage) seem to suggest that it has external.

It properly states it somewhere in the standard, but I have a hard time finding it.

##### My experiment

2 sources files and 1 header:

```cpp
// source.hpp

#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print_size() {
    std::cout << "Size: " << sizeof(T) << std::endl;
}

void call_print_size();
```

```cpp
// source.cpp

#include "source.hpp"

void call_print_size() {
    return print_size<int>();
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include "source.hpp"

int main() {
    print_size<int>();
    call_print_size();
}
```

I'm compiling using MSVC from VS2022 Developer Command Prompt:

```
cl main.cpp source.cpp /std:c++17 /EHsc
```

If I'm correct, this would create 2 definitions of the `int`-instantiation of `print_size`; one in `source.cpp` and one in `main.cpp`. I would expect this to break the One-Definition Rule, if they have external linkage - however, it works just fine.

Comment: *"My own experiments show the instanstiation..."* Trial and error is not a good way to learn c++ imo.

Comment: *" I would expect this to break the One-Definition Rule..."* No, the linker can discard the other definitions and just use one of them, in this case

Comment: Template functions are inline by default. And `inline` in C++ rougly means "compiler you can pick any definition you like, because all definitions will be the same"

Comment: "Trial and error is not a good way to learn c++ imo" I hardly disagree. *Only* learning by trial and error, yes. But experiementing with the concepts you read about (which *can* be quite hairy) is a good way to get a better intuition for things. But confirming your found results with some concrete specification is of course important - which is exactly why I asked this question. Because something seemed off.

Comment: @maltebp Yes ofcourse, trial and error is ok as long as one is also using some reference book/documentation etc alongside.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: It’s not true that templated functions are inline by default; they just behave similarly with regard to the ODR.  `inline` has other effects (on definition necessity, explicit instantiation, and exposures of internal-linkage entities) that templates don’t automatically get.

Comment: @DavisHerring Then I have learned something :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function template declared **without** the keyword `static` at namespace scope(and some other conditions see below) have **external linkage**.

From [Linkage documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#External_linkage):

> Any of the following names declared at namespace scope have external linkage, unless they are declared in an unnamed namespace or their declarations are attached to a named module and are not exported(since C++20):
>
> - **names of all templates not listed above (that is, not function templates declared static).**

---

Additionally, from [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition):

> There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: class type, enumeration type, inline function, inline variable(since C++17), templated entity (template or member of template, but not full template specialization), as long as all of the following is true:
>
> - **each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens** (typically, appears in the same header file)
>
> If all these requirements are satisfied, the program behaves as if there is only one definition in the entire program. Otherwise, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Basically the linker can discard other definitions and just use any one of them(assuming they are exactly the same).

Comment: I will reluctantly accept this answer. It answers the concrete question I asked about (about the linkage of non-member template function), but it does not explain why my experiement works. As you hinted at in your comment (not your answer), the reason my experiment works is because the linker can discard one of the definitions, because they are the same (this is specified [here, under One-Definiton Rule]https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#External_linkage)